# SQL Where Clause Help Needed

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    A   B   C
1   bob 55  0
2   bob 55  1
```

I need help with my where clause. The example above shows Bob has two records. I only want to show records if all of Bob's records have a value of 1 in column C. If one of Bob's records has a value of 0 then it should return nothing for Bob. Currently I'm only able to get it to return the one record that has a value of 1.

Existing query

```
select a, b, c
from table
where b = 55 and c = 1
```

Comment: So - are 0 and 1 the only possible values in column `C`? Can it be `null`? Also, can `A` or `B` ever be `null`? And: if you have two identical rows, with `bob 55 1`, do you need to return both of them? (That is, keep the duplicates from the base table, if they exist?) Or is it guaranteed that there will NOT be duplicates in the inputs?

Comment: 0 and 1 are the only possible values in column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and t2.c <> 1
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest slightly modified SQL (included the WHERE clause spec'd by Gordon):

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c
from table t
where t.b = 55 and t.c = 1 and not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b and t2.c = 0
                 );
```

Massimino's solution also works, assuming column c only ever has values of 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NOT EXISTS as follows

```
  select a, b, c
  from table t
  where t.b = 55 and not exists (select 1 from table t2 
  where t2.b=t.b and t2.c=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub query that finds any records equal to one. If that occurs, you would not include them.

```
    select a, b, c
    from table as t
    where not exists (
       select * 
       from table as t1 
       where t.a = t1.a and IsNull(t1.c, -1) <> 1
    )
```

This way, it won't matter what variety of values for column c could occur, they'll have a record even if you get some nulls (Just in case you're not familiar with your data.). The sub query inside the parenthesis can be run by itself to test or see if you need other criteria.

You could join this table to itself and accomplish something similar, but I think this code example shows intent.